# How to extract attributes for the specific text in PDF using c#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-framework-version

I'm a RPA Developer, I want to extract specific text attributes from pdf file using c#, for ex: if you take any rpa tool like uipath, it will have uiexplorer where if I select any text in pdf file it will pop up with attributes for that text:


. 
Now I want to replicate same thing as what uiexplorer does in C# means I need the above xml code when I select any text in Pdf file. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I believe some PDF files will not have proper formatting. I have been working with PDF data extraction and it is a painful process to achieve it. If you have PDF files with similar structure, you could look for a pattern and extract using string operations.

Comment: @SripadRaj how do I look for a pattern in similar type of pdf??

Comment: Do a `Read PDF Text` activity on your pdf files, if you see a pattern like a word occurring in same place for all your pdf files, you could use a logic to extract your desired data.